# Keyup Event Not Triggered When iFrame in Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, keyup

Let me start by saying I have **no** control over the iframe.

Like "stumbling" I let the user navigate to the next page by using the right arrow key.

The problem is that if the user has clicked anywhere inside of the iframe window, the keyup event on the containing document is ignored.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', null, function(event) {
        var stumblenext = $('#stumblenext');
        if (event.keyCode == 39) { top.location=stumblenext.attr('href'); }
        if (event.keyCode == 37) { history.back(); }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you detect that the focus is on the iframe change the focus to some other element on your page.

Script :

```
function changeFocus() {
    if (document.activeElement == document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]) {
        document.getElementById("YOUR_ID").focus();
    }
}

window.setInterval(changeFocus, 1000); // Set time accordingly
```

Comment: this is what makes "sense" but then how does stumbleupon do it?

Comment: technically the same issue "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of null "

Comment: You should use an appropriate id inplace of `YOUR ID` in the above code. Make sure that `document.getElementById(YOUR-ID)` is not null, i.e. there exists an element with id=YOUR-ID.

Comment: ...right. I'm referring to the console message once a click has been triggered inside of the iframe. Initially, this error is not thrown (if fact, I actually have the console output a message on that interval we set...) however, once I click inside the iframe, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of null " is thrown... seeing as I don't have access to the contents of the frame and even if i did, there probably wouldn't be a frame with the same name. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try binding `keyup` on the iframe as well.

```
$(document, $("#idOfiFrame").contents()).on('keyup', null, function(event) {
        var stumblenext = $('#stumblenext');
        if (event.keyCode == 39) { top.location=stumblenext.attr('href'); }
        if (event.keyCode == 37) { history.back(); }
    });
```